# Unable to save audience in navigation link

Tags: 2013, audience-targeting

I'm trying to create a search navigation (Site Settings -> Search -> Search Settings -> Configure Seach Navigation) which is only visible to a specific set of users (audience).

Unfortunately I can select the specific group in the dialogue and hit "OK" but nothing is saved which I can see when I reopen the dialogue. Moreover the audience is not considered when opening the site.

I have tested this in three different farms and all of them behave the same way. Either all the farms are somehow messed up or it is possibly a "bug".

Can somebody please try to set an audience to search navigation and check in which way is behaving on their site.

Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing the same behavior; we are using SP 2013 with the October 2013 CU applied. I am going to submit to MS as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your feed @cchance. I should have noted in my original question that we are running on October 2013 CU in one of the farms as well.
Could you tell whats the best to file a bug for this at MSFT?

Comment: I also have the issue on October CU. I didn't see anything specific in the December CU notes referring to this fix, have you tried on Dec CU? Did a bug end up getting logged?

Comment: Any news on this from anybody?

Comment: Also having the same issue on multiple environments (RTM, March 2013 CU, SP1+July 2014CU). Anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 2):

We reported this to MS Support and the behaviour is fixed with the "September 9, 2014 Cumulative Update for SharePoint Server 2013 package"

We checked the fix on three farms and it worked. Just don't be confused by the error description in th KB article as it does not seem to have anything to do with this problem here.

You can the CU here https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2883068

Ben